# Recursive function returns undefined in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, c, recursion, math

My Function in javscript:

```js
function gcd(a , b){
    if (b == 0){
        console.log(a);
        return;
    }
    return gcd(b , a%b);
}
```

When called

```js
gcd(270 , 192);
```

OUTPUT:

```
6
```

but when this:

```js
console.log(gcd(270 , 192);
```

OUTPUT:

```js
6
undefined
```

In c

```
typedef double num;
num gcd(num a , num b){
    if (b == 0){
        return a;
    }
    gcd(b , (int)a%(int)b);
}

int main(void){
printf("%d\n" (int)gcd(270, 192));
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
6
```

**What is wrong with my javascript code?**

Comment: I added ```return a; ``` and it still was the same

Comment: `return;` means "return `undefined`".

Comment: `if (b == 0) return a`

Comment: In your `c` version you have `return a`,  so don't leave it out for the JS version,..